# Return simple array from array of objects

Tags: typescript

Let's say we have this array of objects

```
array = [
    { id: 1, type: 'car' },
    { id: 2, type: 'bus' },
    { id: 3, type: 'train' }
];
```

and I want to loop through this array to end up with:

```
result = ['car','bus','train']
```

so easy, I did it below

```
result: string[] = [];
array.forEach((item) => {
    result.push(item.type);
});
```

...but it sounds like too much primitive code, is there a better solution in TypeScript?

Comment: I would definitely use a `map` instead of `forEach`: `const result: string[] = array.map((item): string => item.type)`

Comment: I don't think the explicit type annotations are needed as TypeScript is smart enough to infer those.

Comment: @Alexander Nied, thank you so much, I felt there is a better solution, I'm new to typescript and your answer is very appreciated.